# Assigning an out-of-range integer to a signed char type

Tags: c++, type-conversion

`signed char a = 128;`
Assuming that a byte is 8 bits, is this undefined?
What I know is that assigning an out-of-range value to a signed type is undefined, but Bjarne Stroustrup says in C++ Programming language that if I assign the integer 255 to a char on an 8-bits bytes machine where a char is signed the result is -1.

Comment: Source: The C++ Programming Language - 4th Edition - 6.2.3.1  Signed and Unsigned Characters - Page 142

Comment: It's implementation-defined  (the compiler must document the behaviour)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is this undefined?

No.

> What I know is that assigning an out-of-range value to a signed type is undefined

Also no.

The rule that governs this is conversions between integer types. Whether the conversion is for initialisation or assignment does not matter.

When converting integer value to a signed integer type,
if the result is not representable, then:

In the <strike>current</strike> standard C++17: The resulting value will be implementation defined.

In the <strike>upcoming</strike> standard C++20: The value will be concruent with the original value modulo 2<sup>N</sup>, where N is the width of the destination type (just like with unsigned integers). -1 is congruent with 255 modulo 2<sup>8</sup>.

---

Note that unlike conversion, the behaviour of  signed arithmetic overflow is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I still have a question, C++ Primer states that "If we assign an out-of-range value to an object of signed type, the result is undefined". Is that wrong or there is something I don't understand?

Comment: @Mason that looks like a mistake. It is at least slightly misleading.

Comment: +1 coming after reading that line from C++ Primer, which seems to be inaccurate given the above discussion. Also, think about this, if `int` to `signed char` *could* have undefined behaviors, it would be pointless to have `static_cast<char>(std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)));` where `toupper` returns an `int`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper

Comment: Does that mean that signed integer overflow is simply *impossible* for `signed char` and `short int` types (assuming char < short < int)? (What I mean with impossible is that signed integer overflow can still happen, but not by exceeding the range of either `signed char` or `short int`.) The reasoning being that the usual arithmetic conversions will promote both operands to at least `int` before applying an implementation defined implicit conversion on the result.

Comment: @303 Indeed. Since there aren't arithmetic operations below the rank of `int`, you can overflow only by exceeding the limit of `int` (or greater for higher ranked integers).

Answer (score 0):

By default in C and C++, result of the overflow/underflow operation is *UNDEFINED*. What happens if you overflow/underflow a signed variable type is obsecure which means it could be wrapped around(it is assumed by many compilers) or may dump the core or terminates the program etc.
**But compiler developers usually doesn't strictly conform to this definition and usually wraps around these built-in types**

**Here's a section from The C++ Programming Language 4th By Edition Bjarne Stroustrup(page.259)**

```
void f()
{
    int i = 1;
    while (0 < i) ++i;
    cout << "i has become negative!" << i << '\n';
}
//This will (eventually) try to increase i past the largest integer. What happens then is undefined, but
//typically the value ‘‘wraps around’’ to a negative number (on my machine −2147483648).
```

here what gnu says about it

> Also, overflow can occur when converting an out-of-range value to a
> signed integer type. Here a standard implementation must define what
> happens, but this might include raising an exception. In practice all
> known implementations support silent wraparound in this case, so you
> need not worry about other possibilities.
> Blockquote

[And please check this great article and see how the other fundamental programs rely on ungranteed signed overflow.](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Signed-Overflow-Examples.html#Signed-Overflow-Examples)